# How to convert from Avro GenericRecord to JSON without adding schema name?

Tags: java, avro, confluent-schema-registry, fasterxml

I have 2 schemas:

**Event.avsc:**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.onemount.jobs.transform.schema.avro",
  "name": "Event",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "mtp_interest_submit",
      "type": ["null", "InterestSubmitParam"],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

**InterestSubmitParam.avsc:**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.onemount.jobs.transform.schema.avro",
  "name": "InterestSubmitParam",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "interest",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm consuming Avro messages from Kafka Confluent (with `specific.avro.reader=false`) and need to convert from `GenericRecord` to `ObjectNode`. This is the result:

```
{
  "id": "c8b76e58-9803-4c78-9f82-a185bda1cabf",
  "mtp_interest_submit": {
    "com.onemount.jobs.transform.schema.avro.InterestSubmitParam": {
      "interest": [
        "fashion",
        "travel"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm expected it should be:

```
{
  "id": "c8b76e58-9803-4c78-9f82-a185bda1cabf",
  "mtp_interest_submit": {
    "interest": [
      "fashion",
      "travel"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I fix it. This is my converter code:

```
GenericRecord genericRecord = ...
try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(genericRecord.getSchema());
    JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(genericRecord.getSchema(), outputStream);
    writer.write(genericRecord, encoder);
    encoder.flush();

    return new String(outputStream.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't make `mtp_interest_submit` nullable and the type name won't be there

Comment: @OneCricketeer ty. Adding non-null fields may violate full compatibility, i will consider this approach at last

Comment: The alternative is to build a new POJO model, but it would effectively be the same class definition as building a SpecificRecord from the schema, so maybe look at using Jackson Avro Objectmapper instead of plain Avro API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `jackson-dataformat-avro`, the problem has been resolved:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new AvroFactory());

GenericRecord genericRecord = ...;
try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(genericRecord.getSchema());
    BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outputStream, null);
    writer.write(genericRecord, encoder);
    encoder.flush();

    byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

    return mapper.readerFor(ObjectNode.class)
            .with(new AvroSchema(genericRecord.getSchema()))
            .readValue(bytes);
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-avro</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
```